# How can I fix my code in Livecode?

Tags: livecode

EDIT:
I've fixed the problem. It turns out that it was picking a new word straight after the script below and was using the length of *that* word rather than the word I wanted it to use. My bad! Ignore this question if you're stumbling upon it just now.

```
on openCard
   setup randomword
   put randomword into fld "testfield"
end openCard

command test
   put 11 into tNumObjs
   put length(randomword) into tLen
   repeat with x = 1 to tNumObjs
      show fld ("letter"&x)
   end repeat
end test

on setup pRandomWord
   put 11 into tNumObjs
   put length(pRandomWord) into tLen
   repeat with x = 1 to tNumObjs
      put empty into fld ("letter"&x)
      hide fld ("letter"&x)
      if x <= tLen then
         put char x of pRandomWord into fld ("letter"&x)
         show grc ("Line"&x)
      else
         hide grc ("Line" & x)
      end if
   end repeat
end setup

on checkForCharacterMatch pUserChar
   local noMatch = true
   repeat with N = 1 to (length(randomword))
      put long id of field ("letter" & N) into theLetter
      put long id of graphic ("Line" & N) into theLine
      if (the text of theLetter = pUserChar) then
         show theLetter
         hide theLine
         put false into noMatch
      end if
   end repeat
   --if noMatch then
      -- DO PENALTY STUFF HERE
   --end if
end checkForCharacterMatch
```

Comment: So you're coding a game of hangman here ...?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have 11 fields for other purposes and the number of the first LetterN field is 12. Probably you used field numbers when you started writing your script but now you're using field names. Remove "+11" and it should work:

```
repeat with N = 1 to (length(randomword))
```

If this doesn't solve it, please explain why you add 11.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, there are 11 char-width fields. The 11 is a typo, I've edited that out.